# Is there any risk to enable internet in SharePoint servers

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, certificate, validation-error

I got a critical certificate validation error ID 8321 in event viewer!

> It took 300000 milliseconds and has exceeded the execution time thresholds.

I checked for a lot of solutions on the Internet but none seem to work for me.

One of the solution is enabling the internet access over on the SharePoint servers.

Is it risky to enable internet in SharePoint farm? If yes, then how can solve this critical error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short,** Yes, it's risky!!

> You can get more details at https://security.stackexchange.com

**Have you tried to add the below entry to the `hosts` file?**

```
172.0.0.1  crl.microsoft.com
```

**Also,** check the suggested workaround at

- [Best Practices for CRL Checking on SharePoint Servers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2014/05/01/best-practices-for-crl-checking-on-sharepoint-servers/)
- [How Certificate Revocation Works](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee619754(v=ws.10))

If all the above mentioned didn't help you, so at least try to **only** enable internet access to this URL `crl.microsoft.com`

Answer (score 0):

It is not risky but it really depends if your customer is ok with this . Crl time outs are commonly fixed by exposing SharePoint servers to internet .